# Ultrawide camera not showing up in CameraManager#getCameraIdList and CameraCharacteristics#getPhysicalCameraIds

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera2

I want to make an app that records video using the ultrawide camera. I am using ASUS ROG Phone II. `CameraManager#getCameraIdList` only gives me "0" and "1", which are the main front camera and the selfie camera. `CameraCharacteristics#getPhysicalCameraIds` of the front camera gives an empty array. `CameraInfo#getZoomState().getValue().getMinZoomRatio()` is 1.0, plus my phone is just Android 10 so `CameraControl#setZoomRatio()` with value < 1.0 won't work. The GCam mod for my phone model does support the ultra wide camera so I think it should be possible for third party app to use the ultrawide camera. How do I select the ultrawide camera using the Camera2 API? Am I missing something?

Comment: Any updates on this?